# Is the "synchronized access of threads" the opposite to "synchronizing the shared object"?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, synchronization, locking

What does the phrase:

> "We are getting inconsistent output as the access of these threads to
>   the Printer object is synchronized"

in the article [Threads and Thread Synchronization in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26130/Threads-and-Thread-Synchronization-in-C) mean?

What are "consistent output" and "synchronized access"?
Does the "synchronized access of the threads" synonym to inconsistent and the opposite/antonym to the following in the article description of synchronized shared object use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the “synchronized access of threads” the opposite to “synchronizing
>   the shared object”?

No, these have the same meaning.

The article should say:

> "We are getting inconsistent output as the access of these threads to
>   the Printer object is **not** synchronized"

> What are "consistent output" and "synchronized access"?

Consistent output is the same each time you run the program. Synchronized access is mutually exclusive access: only one thread could access the resource

> Does the "synchronized access of the threads" synonym to inconsistent
>   and the opposite/antonym to the following in the article description
>   of synchronized shared object use?

No.